# Cyclic wave displacement modifier on a plane produces wave profiles as seen in blue, I wish to achieve red (proper sine waves):

Tags: modeling, modifiers

In black you see the displacement produced by the wave modifier. This is quite confusing as it is not a proper sine wave, which I am attempting to produce. Is there a setting I am missing which would result in the sine wave so beautifully indicated by the red markings?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what's the algorithm behind the wave modifier, but you can use *Math Function* addon, or do an equivalent in Geometry Nodes - below I calculate $y = \sin(xπ)$:

[image]

(the original line length is 6 units)